# RSS to HTML with varying number of elements

Tags: php, rss

I've adapted the code found here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp to turn XML into HTML, and it works fine.

But what I'm stuck on is getting it to show **all** the items in a feed when the feed can have varying numbers of items. The feed is published daily and can have anywhere from 12-20 articles in it, and I want to show all of them.

In the For Loop `for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)` if I set the condition to be greater than the number of articles, I get an error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName()`, so I can't just set it to a big number.

I get the same error if I just remove the condition.

I can't figure out how to count the number of items, either; if I could do that the solution would be easy.

The feed is created in-house so I could ask my colleague to insert the number of items in the feed; is that the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of items in the feed, you can go through them all using a `foreach` loop. Here is an example using the [RSS feed from the PHP tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php&sort=newest). Have a look at the rss format so you can see what each entry looks like, and compare it to the code below.

```
# start off like the w3schools code...
$xml=("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php&sort=newest");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

# StackOverflow uses the <entry> element for each separate item.
# find all the "entry" items. This returns an array of matching entry elements
$items = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('entry');

# go through the array of "entry" elements one at a time
# $items is the array of <entry> elements
# $i is set to each <entry> in turn, starting from the first one on the page
foreach ($items as $i) {

    # some sample code to get the title, tags, and link
    $title = $i->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $href = $i->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
    $tags = $i->getElementsByTagName('category');
    $tag_arr = [];
    foreach ($tags as $t) {
        $tag_arr[] = $t->getAttribute('term');
    }
    echo "Title: $item_title; tags: " . implode(", ", $tag_arr) . ";\nhref: $href\n\n";
}
```

Using a `foreach` loop means you are not stuck with having to work out how many items you have in your array, and you don't have to set up an array iterator using `for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)`.

Comment: Thanks! I asked this on r/php as well and someone there also mentioned changing it to foreach instead. But someone else said there's a "length" element perfect for this, which works great!
    
    for($i=0; $i < $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item')->length; $i++)

Comment: I don't usually use `for ($i=0; $i<...;$++)` unless I need to keep track of the number of the element that I'm on. Usually, it's enough to say `foreach ($arr as $i)` -- it's easier to type, and you don't have to faff around with array indexes (i.e. you can use `$i` instead of `$arr[$i]`). If this works, please click the tick by the answer to show that the problem has been solved. Thank you!